# Fantasy novel involving a painter

Tags: story-identification

- The main character is a painter. The book is about him but it might not always be told from a  first-person perspective
- The main character has a sister with a name that starts with 'Sav' (I think)
- I remember that he paints and there is something magical about the way he paints. I don't remember if he paints people into paintings or somehow steals their life by painting (it's not Dorian Grey!)
- I think near the end he disappears and his sister finds a lifelike painting of him and finds out it *is* him.
- If I remember correctly, they had dark hair and the book was set with kind of a Mexican/Italian kind of look to the people. Possibly a desert surroundings?

Comment: You should split this into two questions.

Comment: oh sorry I will do that then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're describing [*The Golden Key*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Key_%28novel%29), by Jennifer Roberson, Melanie Rawn, and  Kate Elliott

It's set in an alternate Spain; the lead character, Sario Grijalva, is a painter, who can use his paintings to perform magic. He has a cousin called Saavedra.

I don't remember the incident you mention about him disappearing into a painting - it's been a long time since I read this - but

> at one point in the book, Sario imprisons someone inside a painting for years - the painting starts off with the person coming through a door at the back of a room, and over time, slowly changes as he walks the length of the room

Comment: You are fantastic! In my original post I mentioned I thought I had made up that ending, That is definitely the book! This place is great!